# Djangoの開発サーバーに外部からアクセスしたい

Tags: centos, apache, django, network

**質問**
Djangoで開発サーバーを起動後、ローカル環境外の端末からアクセスしようとしてもできませんでした。
下記実施済みの対策以外で必要な操作があるのでしょうか。もしくは他に原因があるのでしょうか。

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。他に必要な情報がございましたらお申し付けください。

**実施済み**
関係していそうなプログラムの停止(起動した状態でも試しました。)

```
systemctl stop httpd
systemctl stop firewalld
apachectl stop
```

setting.pyのALLOWED_HOSTSの設定変更

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

IPを指定した開発サーバーの起動
(manage.pyとdaphneを両方とも試しましたがダメでした。daphneでアクセスできるようにしたいです。)

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
daphne -b 0.0.0.0:8000 [mysite].asgi:application
```

下記アドレスでアクセスしたところ、長いローディング画面後に接続できないとの表示がでました。

```
http://[IPアドレス]:8000
```

ローカル環境内のcurlでは通信できました。

**サーバー環境**
CentOS 8.3.2011
Python 3.8.3
Django 3.2.9
channels 3.0.4
daphne 3.0.2
Apache 2.4.37

**簡易物理ネットワーク構成図**
[image: 簡易物理ネットワーク構成図]

Comment: 状況的にネットワーク回りが影響していそうです。ネットワーク構成図は出せますか？

Comment: keitaro_so 様　コメントありがとうございます。返答が遅くなり申し訳ございません。
ネットワーク構成図というものを知らなかったため調べてみました。物理構成図と論理構成図があるようですがこのような場合はどちらをお渡しすればよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: 場合によっては物理が必要になることもありますが、論理構成図いただければ十分かと思います。

Comment: @keitaro_so 様
大変申し訳ございません。知識不足により論理ネットワーク構成図の作図ができませんでした。不必要かもしれませんが、非常に簡易的な物理ネットワーク構成図を掲載いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @keitaro_so 様のご意見で頂いた「ネットワーク回りが影響していそう」というお言葉を参考に、他の環境で調べてみたところ接続できました。現環境の問題点を含めて改めて調べなおそうと思います。@keitaro_so 様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問投稿者です。

コメント欄のご意見ありがとうございました。

頂いたコメントを参考に自宅回線以外の回線を使用して通信したところ、期待していた通信に成功しました。

このことより、原因がWebサーバーやファイアウォールの設定によるサーバー側のものではなく、クライアント側のネットワーク環境が原因だと思われますので「外部からアクセスしたい」という本質問の趣旨は解決できたものとさせていただきます。

私の確認・知識不足により、ご迷惑をおかけいたしました。
コメントによりお手伝いいただいた方に感謝いたします。